# Failed to get the culture Resource in .net 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, data-annotations

Good morning,

I'm using .netCore 3.1 and in my model I have the attributeValidation of email, but the return message is always for default, I can't get the message in the expected culture.

I think that the structure folders is correct and when I inspect the middleware the resource base have this route:

Someone have any idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using .netCore 3.1 and in my model I have the attributeValidation of email, but the return message is always for default, I can't get the message in the expected culture.

I did a test with following code snippet, which work as expected, you can refer to it.

*My testing model class under `Models` folder*

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is not a valid email address")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //...
    //other properties
    //...
}
```

*My resource file `MyModel.fr.resx` and folder structure*

[image]

*Configure localization*

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

services.AddControllersWithViews().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);
```

Test Result

[image]

Besides, you can refer to [this doc about "globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and try these steps to troubleshoot the issue.

1. check if you correctly configure localization and data annotations localization in your app
2. check if browser user select and set language/culture
3. check if you correctly use the dot or path naming convention to organize/name your resource file(s)